# Java Scripting API (JSR223) groovy language limitations

Tags: java, groovy, beanshell, jsr223

I want to know the limitation(s) when executing code using [Java Scripting API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html) (JSR223) for example using `Beanshell` or `groovy` language,

What **can't** be done/execute using the language chosen as groovy? Is there some language capabilities that can't be used inside script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java scripting API uses [AccessController.doPrivileged()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged-java.security.PrivilegedAction-) to run the script, so depending on context there are could be any restrictions done.

For example restricted access a file system...

Comment: are there also language limitation? e.g. can't use static compilation, can't use keyword, etc...

Comment: groovy executed as a script. groovy script before running converted into a class. all the code (except methods/functions) executed as a method `main` in java. and you can't declare static variables inside the method. but you can declare inner class with static vars in groovy script like: `class MyConst { static int i = 123 }` and access it from script: `MyConst.i`